# Why does close price results have a date shift (one day off) while using GOOGLEFINANCE in a Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates, google-finance

I want to get last 40 days close price of stocks.

I used below formula for the same but the result not showing the last day close price.

```
=QUERY(
      GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:"&B2,"all",$A$2-80,81),
      "SELECT Col5 WHERE Col1 <= date '"&TEXT($A$2+1, "YYYY-MM-DD")&"' order by Col1 desc limit 40",False
       )
```

Where, `B2` is `ticker`, `A2` is `Today()`

It updates next day evening. I mean for example today is `Friday 27 Sep 1:15 PM (India)` but result is showing up to 25 Sep. Data for 26 will be shown today evening.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Can you provide the data you obtain with `=GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:"&B2,"all",$A$2-80,81)` or share a sample sheet ?

Answer (score 1):

### The key word in your formula is not `Query` but `GOOGLEFINANCE`.

Your query is correct. But please take into account the following.

As mentioned under `GOOGLEFINANCE` [documentation page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en):

- `attribute` is one of the following for historical data:

  - `"open"` - The opening price for the specified date(s).
  - **`"close"` - The closing price for the specified date(s)**.
  - `"high"` - The high price for the specified date(s).
  - `"low"` - The low price for the specified date(s).
  - `"volume"` - The volume for the specified date(s).
  - **`"all"` - All of the above**.
- `end_date|num_days` - [ OPTIONAL ] - **The end date when fetching historical data, or the number of days from start_date for which to return data.**
- **If any date parameters are specified, the request is considered historical** and only the historical attributes are allowed.
- Quotes are not sourced from all markets and **may be delayed up to 20 minutes**.
- **Dates passed into `GOOGLEFINANCE` are treated as noon UTC time. Exchanges that close before that time may be shifted by a day.**

Taking into account the above quotes as well as that there is a **[time difference](http://www.timebie.com/timezone/indianewyork.php) with India (UTC +5:30)** the results you get are the expected ones.

*Extra: Not even changing your time zone under `Spreadsheet settings` will make any difference (as others tried before).*

Answer (score 0):

`=index(query({GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"price",K1+1,TODAY());{today(),**GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"price")**}},"select sum(Col2) pivot Col1"),2)`

You can add today's price in the list with the help of above query, where `K1` is date.